# Creating a deeply nested object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I've built a small API that, when posted a JSON object, creates the representative model records. The data looks like this:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "email": "michael@myemail.com",
    "first_name": "Michael T. Smith",
    "last_name": "",
    "shipping_address_1": "",
    "telephone": "5551211212",
    "source": "Purchase"
  },
  "order": {
    "system_order_id": "1070",
    "shipping_address_1": "",
    "billing_address_1": "123 Your Street",
    "shipping": "0",
    "tax": "0",
    "total": "299",
    "invoice_date": 1321157461,
    "status": "PROCESSING",
    "additional_specs": "This is my info!",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "quantity": "1",
        "price": "239",
        "product": "Thing A",
        "comments": "comments"
        "specification": {
          "width": "12",
          "length": "12",
        },
      },
      {
        "quantity": "1",
        "price": "239",
        "product": "Thing A",
        "comments": "comments"
        "specification": {
          "width": "12",
          "length": "12",
        },
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

The question is how to create the nested objects. My models are setup as such:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  belongs_to :customer

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :specifications
end

class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :LineItem 
end
```

I'm trying to create the records using this code:

```
@order = @customer.orders.build(@data[:order])
@order.save
```

Is there a better way to do this? Currently I'm getting this error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ApiController#purchase_request LineItem(#70310607516240) expected, got Hash(#70310854628220)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) defines a new setter method for the association: the original name with `_attributes` appended to it.

In your case, there is a `line_items_attributes=` method on your `Order` model, which is what you need to use to take advantage of the nested attributes feature.  Something as simple as swapping the key before building the model would probably work, e.g.:

```
@data[:order][:line_items_attributes] = @data[:order].delete(:line_items)
@order = @customer.orders.build(@data[:order])
@order.save
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use accepts_nested_attributes_for like this:
(in my example, Products has_many ProductionItineraries and ProductionItineraries belongs_to Products)

model/product.rb

```
has_many :production_itineraries, dependent: :delete_all
accepts_nested_attributes_for :production_itineraries, allow_destroy: true
```

model/production_itinerary.rb

```
belongs_to :product
```

To instantiate:

```
products = Product.new
products.production_itineraries.build(other_production_itineraries_fields)
```

Doing this, after save `products`, the production_itinerary object will be save automatically, with the respective product_id field